# Quadratic twist of modular L-function

Tags: number-theory, l-functions

(Sorry for my poor english..)
Let $F(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a(n)q^n\in S_{2k}(\Gamma_0(N),\chi_0))$ be a newform with trivial character $\chi_0$. For $\text{Re}(s)>>0$, we can define 
\begin{equation}
L(F,s):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a(n)}{n^s}
\end{equation}
and by analytic continuation, we can define modular $L$-function. And many mathematicians also research the quadratic twists of modular L-function. That is, for a fundamental discriminant $D$, let $\chi_{D}$ be a character of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$, then for $\text{Re}(s)>>0$,
\begin{equation}
L(F\otimes \chi_{D}, s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a(n)\chi_{D}(n)}{n^s}
\end{equation}.
(And by analytic continuation, we can define $L(F\otimes \chi_{D},s).$)

I think many mathematicians are interested in $L(F\otimes \chi_{D},k)$ with $(D,N)=1$. For example, Lemma 9.2 in Ono's book "The web of modularity : Arithmetic of the coefficients of Modular forms and $q$-series",
\begin{equation}
\Lambda(F\otimes \chi_{D},s)=\epsilon\cdot \chi_{D}(-N)\Lambda(F\otimes \chi_{D},2k-s)
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
\Lambda(F,s):=(2\pi)^{-s}\Gamma(s)N^{s/2}L(F,s)
\end{equation}
and there is an $\epsilon\in \{\pm 1\}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\Lambda(F,s)=\epsilon \Lambda(F,2k-s).
\end{equation}
My question is..

Is it true for when $(D,N)\neq 1$? And why are many mathematicians interested in $(D,N)=1$?

Comment: $\sum_n a(n)n^{-s}$ never converges for $\Re(s) > 0$. It is easy to show that for a weight $k$ cusp form $a(n)= O(n^{k/2})$, to get $a(p)=O(p^{(k-1)/2},a(n)=O(n^{(k-1)/2+\epsilon})$ [we need](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Petersson_conjecture) the Weil conjectures, so that (for a newform) the normalized L-function $\sum_n a(n) n^{-(k-1)/2-s}$  is in the Selberg class (similar properties, critical strip, RH, functional equation as $\zeta(s)$). If $g$ has multiplicative coefficients and is modular for $\Gamma_1(N)$ then $f(-1/(dz))=cf(z)$ where $f$ is the newform underlying $g$

Comment: @reuns Thanks for kindly reply!. So, I assumed that the real part of $s$ is large enough. And then we define modular $L$-function by analytic continuation. My question is $D$-quadratic twist of modular L-function when $(D,N)\neq 1$.

Comment: Sorry I meant $f(-1/(dz))=cf^*(z)$ (where $f^*$ is the newform with complex conjugate coefficients, see [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg_class#Definition)).

Comment: Yes, it is true when $(D,N) > 1$, with several caveats.

(1) The "correct" definition of the twisted $L$-function is not the Dirichlet series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a(n) \chi(n) n^{-s}$; this can be off when $(n,D,N) > 1$ (in the same way that the "correct" $L$-function associated to an imprimitive Dirichlet character is the $L$-function for the primitive Dirichlet character). See my MO answer here for a high-level description: https://mathoverflow.net/a/272802/3803...

Comment: ...(2) Similarly, the completed $L$-function $\Lambda(F\otimes \chi_D,s)$ needs more care with regards to the presence of $\epsilon \cdot \chi_D(-N)$ and $N^{s/2}$; the complex number $\epsilon \cdot \chi_D(-N)$ is replaced by something else (which still has absolute value $1$) that depends sensitively (but complicatedly!) on $F$ and $\chi_D$, and similarly $N^{s/2}$ is replaced by $N^{\prime s/2}$ for some $N'$ that is related to $D,N$ and depends sensitively on $F$ and $\chi_D$. There isn't exactly a general formula for either of these, unfortunately.